# Как вывести значение переменной через printf() C++

Tags: c++, printf

Задача такова:

> По значению температуры **F**, заданному в градусах Фаренгейта,
> определить значение температуры **C** в градусах Цельсия. Температура по
> Цельсию **C** и температура по Фаренгейту **F** связаны
> соотношением: **C = (F – 32)·5/9**

Надо написать код, который будет это выполнять и выводить в консоли Windows, но я не могу понять как работает printf(), у меня при вводе температуры в Фаренгейтах программа выдаёт даже не цифру.

> Введите температуру в градусах Фаренгейта = 132
> Температура в градусах Цельсия 005BF71C
> C:\Users\Beleberda\source\repos\Лаб_01_14\Debug\Лаб_01_14.exe (процесс 5012) завершил работу с кодом 0.
> Чтобы автоматически закрывать консоль при остановке отладки, включите параметр "Сервис" ->"Параметры" ->"Отладка" -> "Автоматически закрыть консоль при остановке отладки".
> Нажмите любую клавишу, чтобы закрыть это окно…

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;  /* Температура в градусах Цельсия */
    int f;  /* Температура в градусах Фаренгейта */

    /* Включение кириллицы в консоли */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");

    /* Ввод F */
    printf("Введите температуру в градусах Фаренгейта = ");
    scanf_s("%f", &f);

    /* Вычисление C */
    c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;

    /* Вывод результата */
    printf("Температура %s %p", "в градусах Цельсия" , &c);
    getchar();

}
```

В Гугле подробного объяснения этой функции не нашёл. Буду благодарен если кто-нибудь объяснит как работает printf() и подскажет правильный вариант исполнения. Задача для лабы в университете, если что...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам подробное объяснение — https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Вам надо 1. указывать верный формат вводимой/выводимой величины и 2. передавать в `scanf` адрес, в `printf` — значение.

Т.е. если у вас `int f;`, то и читать надо `scanf_s("%d", &f);`, Но сразу замечу, что тогда будут немного неверные ответы, потому что в

c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;

будет использоваться целочисленное деление, т.е. с отбрасыванием дробной части (но, может, это у вас специально так сделано, не знаю).

Соответственно, выводить вам надо тоже целочисленное значение `int c;`, так что надо использовать формат `%d` (ну, если в десятичной системе счисления :)) и передавать `c`. То, что вы делали — это вывод адреса (`%p`) переменной `c`.

```
printf("Температура %s %d", "в градусах Цельсия", c);
```

Только вот это ввод/вывод, свойственный C; в C++ было бы немного проще (вывод строки оставляю двумя частями, как и у вас):

```
cout << "Температура " << "в градусах Цельсия" << c;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, о величайший!!!